# OData 4 Clients and filters with floats

Tags: c#, linq, odata

We're using the [OData 4 Client Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937) to create some proxy classes and query an OData4 service. Everything seems to work fine, except for queries where we want to filter by properties that are floats or doubles.

So for a given query made with an integer filter:

```cs
var ctx = new ODataClient(new Uri("http://..."));
var intFilter = 3;
var results = ctx.Entities.Where(e => e.IntProperty == intFilter).ToList();
```

The resulting query to the service is:

```
Entities?$filter=IntProperty eq 3
```

And we get the filtered results, as expected.

But if we try to filter with a double value, for instance:

```cs
var ctx = new ODataClient(new Uri("http://..."));
var doubleFilter = 0.35d;
var results = ctx.Entities.Where(e => e.DoubleProperty == doubleFilter).ToList();
```

The resulting query ends up being:

```
Entities?$filter=DoubleProperty eq 0.35
```

When in reality it should be:

```
Entities?$filter=DoubleProperty eq 0.35d
```

That little difference at the end results in an exception begin thrown by the service:

```
The query specified in the URI is not valid. 
Numeric string '0.35' is not a valid Int32/Int64/Double/Decimal.
```

Is there any way to configure these proxy clients to do the conversion correctly? Or are we stuck with the AddQueryOption method and having to build our filter "manually" instead of with LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Entities?$filter=DoubleProperty eq 0.35` is actually an expected expression, if you take a look at the [OData protocal 5.1.1.6.1 Primitive Literals](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398153)

*Primitive literals can appear in the resource path as key property values, and in the query part, for example, as operands in $filter expressions. They are represented according to the primitiveLiteral rule in [OData-ABNF].*

And [OData-ABNF](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt) defines the `PrimitiveLiteral` as following:

; in URLs

```
primitiveLiteral = nullValue                  ; plain values up to int64Value
             / ...
             / doubleValue 
             / singleValue 
             / ...

decimalValue = [SIGN] 1*DIGIT ["." 1*DIGIT]

doubleValue = decimalValue [ "e" [SIGN] 1*DIGIT ] / nanInfinity ; IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point number (15-17 decimal digits)
singleValue = doubleValue
```

So i think it's better that your service support to promote 0.35 to double.

To work around this issue, actually you can use `AddQueryOption` as following.

```
ctx.Entities.AddQueryOption("$filter", "DoubleProperty eq 0.35d").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont send it like

```
var doubleFilter = 0.35d;
```

instead send it like

```
decimal doubleFilter = 0.35;
```

this will solve your problem

Comment: I cannot do that as the property I want to filter by is a double, and not a string. If i try it, I get a type mismatch exception: " A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Double' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equals'."

Thank you for your input, nevertheless.

Comment: really, i have faced the same problem but it was fixed same way i answered, i will try to check my code again, and i will update my answer or delete it

Comment: i have checked my code, this was exactly my case, can you try it and let me know